# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: when I call a function (safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have the fallowing error :

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: changeImgSize

But this is a function. I check if I correctly insert the different javascript files and it doesn't seem to have any problem. Here are my different files. Of course I will not show the whole code, just the part where the issue is

**index.html**

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="build/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/imgManagement.js"></script>
<script src="js/MainFaceTracker.js"></script>
<script>
       $(document).ready(documentIsReady); // 'documentIsReady' in 'no_language.js'
<body>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="input" />
</body>
```

**imgManagement.js**

```
function changeImgSize(img){
    // here i just change the size of the img with proportionality

    return img;
}

var addImgToCanvas = function(img){
    var canvas=$('#canvas');
    img=changeImgSize(img);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
};
```

**MainFaceTracker.js**

```
'use strict';
function documentIsReady() {
// All document items are available...
    console.log("documentIsReady");
    new Main(); // Call Main() function
}


var Main = function(){
    console.log('entered- Main');

    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);

    function handleFiles(e) {
        console.log('entered- cameraListener');

        var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        var img = new Image();
        //img.id = 'img';
        img.src = url;

        img.onload = function () {
            console.log('entered- OnLoadImage');

            img=changeImgSize(img); // <-- HERE IS THE ERROR

        };
    }
};
```

I tried to change the order of the call of my files there is still the error. I tested it on chrome and it works fine

Comment: Is the code shown in those files wrapped in an outer function?

Comment: `MainFaceTracker.js` is the main function, it calls every other functions

Comment: That doesn't answer if there are outer wrapping functions not shown. You have a scope issue it sounds like but nothing shown would cause that

Answer (score 0):

Remove Strict Mode and see if the error removed ?